# Sequelize query that ignores whitespace on PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize (v3.31.1) with the Node.js library pg (v6.4.2) for PostgreSQL (v10.1) and I want to perform a search for a reference that ignores whitespace.

For example:

```
reference
---------
ABC 123
```

Ideal usage:

```
Project.findAll({
  where: { reference: 'ABC123' },
  ignoreWhitespace: true
}).then(projects => console.log(projects));
```

Would expect it to match both: `ABC 123` and `ABC123` currently only the exact match works.

What is the idiomatic Sequelize way to get it to match the reference ignoring the spaces?

(I'm using Node.js v8.9.4, npm v5.6.0).

My current attempt:

```
const reference = 'ABC123';
const clause = "UPPER(REPLACE(reference, ' ', '')) = UPPER(:reference)";
const sql = `SELECT * FROM "Projects" WHERE ${clause}`;
sequelize.query(sql, {
  replacements: { reference },
  type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT,
  model: Project,
}).then(projects => console.log(projects));
```

Comment: Your postgreSQL version is too old (v6.4.2). REPLACE function came out since version 7.3 and the current version is 10

Comment: @Dan I think the phrasing was confusing the reference to pg being v6.4.2 was the version of the Node.js library I'm using with Sequelize. The PostgreSQL version is 10.1

Comment: @Dan: "6.4.2" refers to the version of the `pg` library accessing the Postgres server. Not to the Postgres version itself